# I am using ionic app, I am trying to connect mqtt-broker. It is working in android version 8.1 and web, but it is not working in 9 and above versions

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mqtt

I am trying to connect with mqtt broker,  it is working in android version 8.1 and lower but it is not working in 9 and above versions. could you please help me to solve this.
This is ionic info-

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.8.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.2.10
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.5.0) : 1.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 7.23.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

This is network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">*</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

this cofig.xml

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
```

Comment: Is there more detail aside from "not working"? Could you provide the stack trace from the logcat if possible?

Comment: I have provided stack trace below, please check it. Thank you